# Problems when calling an API

Tags: windows, powershell, api, invoke-webrequest

We have two APIs that does a POST and GET requests. Both of them used to work perfectly fine but the API that does POST started giving an error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.`

I have been trying to research for few days and all the KBs pointing to some sort of SSL/TLS and adding this piece of code:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "SystemDefault,Tls12, Tls11, Tls, Ssl3"
```

but I already had this code from the start. However, I cannot find a solution to my problem.

OS : Windows 2012
PowerShell Version: 4.0

```
function funName ($Val1, $Val2) {
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "SystemDefault,Tls12, Tls11, Tls, Ssl3"
    #[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    #[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    $url = "https://someAPI/post.request/do-something"
    $user = "username"
    $pass = "password"
    $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds "

    $Headers = @{
        "Accept"="application/json"
        Authorization = $basicAuthValue
    }

    $Body = @{
        '@type' ='x'
        parm1 = $Val1
        parm2 = $Val2
    }

    #[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers -Method Post -Body $Body  | Out-Null
}

## Deactivation Request ffffffff##
funName -RequestID Val1 adID Val2
```

As stated earlier, this used to work up until last week.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but did you verify that the certificate isn't expired?

Comment: No. They aren't expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a similar request to retrieve data from API and I found out that I was calling my function as `funName -val1 1234 val2 9999` where I was missing "-" on my seconda parameter. As soon as I fixed that it starting working again `funName -val1 1234 -val2 9999` . Thanks Stackoverflow community for the help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Set this to the top of your script:

```
Add-Type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    namespace myTrust
    {
        public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy 
        {
            public bool CheckValidationResult( ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
"@

$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object myTrust.TrustAllCertsPolicy
```